# SQL discrepancy using COUNT command

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do my first steps with SQL. Currently I am trying to analyse a database and stepped over a problem which I can't explain. Eventually someone could give me a hint.

I have a mySQL table ('cap851312') witch has 330.178 table rows. I already imported the table to Excel, and verified this number!

Every single row includes a field (column 'ID_MES_ANO') for the entries date. For the time being, all the date is uniquely set `"201312"`.

Starting the following command, I would expect to see as a result the given number of rows, however the number which appears is 476.598.

```
SELECT movedb.cap851312.ID_MES_ANO, count(*)
   FROM movedb.cap851312;
```

I already imported the file to Excel, and verified the number of lines. Indeed, it is 330.178!

How could I find out, what exactly is going wrong?

---

Update:

I've tried:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM movedb.cap851312
```

This returns as well 476.598.

As I am using workbench, I easily could confirm the numer of 330.178 table rows.

---

Update 2:

The Workbench Table Inspector confirms: "Table rows: 330178"

---

Solved - However unsure why:

I changed the statement to

```
SELECT count(ID_MES_ANO) FROM movedb.cap851512;
```

This time the result is 330178 !

Comment: Try SELECT count(*)
   FROM movedb.cap851312;

Comment: Depending on Excel version the maximum number of rows differs.

Comment: How did you confirm the number of 330.178 table rows using workbench?

Comment: Is it possible that there are rows in your table with `ID_MES_ANO` set to `null`?

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(*)` counts all rows.

`COUNT(ID_MES_ANO)` counts only rows for which `ID_MES_ANO` is not null.

So the difference between the two are the rows where `ID_MES_ANO` is null.

You can verify this with

```
SELECT count(*) FROM movedb.cap851512 WHERE ID_MES_ANO IS NULL;
```

By the way:

```
SELECT movedb.cap851312.ID_MES_ANO, count(*) FROM movedb.cap851312;
```

means: aggregate all rows to one single result row (by using the aggregate function `COUNT` without `GROUP BY`). This result row shows `ID_MES_ANO` and the number of all records. Standard SQL does not allow this, because you don't tell the DBMS which `ID_MES_ANO` of those hundreds of thousands of records to show. MySQL violates the standard here and simply picks one `ID_MES_ANO` arbitrarily from the rows.